# Magento 2: Advanced cart price rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

How can we setup cart price rule if customer purchase more than one time then first item should have actual price(X) but from second to last item, its price should be less (X-5) ? For example customer A adds three items in cart and base price is 15. So for first item it should be 15 but for next two items it should be 10.